# Support for Verigy 93K Offline Results Emulation (ORE)?

Tags: origen-sdk

Is there any support for enabling Verigy 93K Offline Results Emulation (ORE)?  ORE allows test program owners to inject faults or other data types into their test program to check program outcomes.  The purpose is to improve test program quality.  Here are the topic IDs for the V93k technical documentation center:

ORE Overview   : Topic 128475
Setup File           : Topic 128592

Origen can, of course, help create the ORE collateral (XML and ascii files).  But I think the true benefit would be to create a DSL for this type of fault/data injection into the tester platform's various components (flow files, capture memory, measurement instrucment results, etc.).  A simple example would be to program the PMU result for power supply shorts to be above clamp and see if the clamp gets caught by user code and an Alarm bin is assigned to the part.

Here is a short example of the XML file used to inject a fault into a pattern for a specific pin:

```
<offlineResultEmulation>
  <pattern name="testPattern1">
      <site number="1">
        <pin name="Q0">
          <fail xmode_cycle="0"/>
          <fail xmode_cycle="1"/>
          <fail xmode_cycle="2"/>
        </pin>
      </site>
  </pattern>
```

regards

Comment: Don't really know what that means, can you elaborate more on what ORE is and what you might expect Origen to do?

Comment: I updated the original post to address your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no support for that at present and no plans to support it before now.

I don't see that feature being used much within our company, and if anyone is using it then there has not been any push to build support for it into Origen.

Of course, if you can see benefit here then please do drive it's development.

Comment: Will do.  The benefit is the ability to test out very precise device behavior offline.  Origen-SDK has some sort of fault injection regarding the test flow doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, you can fully verify flow branch logic offline using Origen today, that is covered by this video: http://origen-sdk.org/origen/videos/5-create-program-flow/